# What is WinRT remoting?

Tags: process, windows-phone-8, remoting, inter-process-communicat, out-of-process

I'm reading about IPC in Windows Phone 8, and I come across Peter Torr's articles about [Using named events to coordinate foreground apps and background agents](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2013/03/27/using-named-events-to-coordinate-foreground-apps-and-background-agents.aspx). In the bottom of his article, he mentioned `WinRT remoting` as the advanced technique for IPC between foreground and background process.

So what is `WinRT remoting`? Is it somehow related to `out of process COM server`?